# Cursor flashing on the non-client area when using IDirect3DDevice9::SetCursorProperties

Tags: winapi, cursor, direct3d, nonclient

I have an application running under Direct3D9. The application is using the Direct3D HW cursor API (`IDirect3DDevice9::SetCursorProperties` et al.) to control the cursor. Almost everything works fine:

- when inside of the application window, the cursor specified by SetCursorProperties is shown
- when outside of the application window, normal OS cursor is displayed as needed by desktop or other windows

The problem is with the non-client area of my window (the title bar, screen edges). When moving in the non-client area, the cursor corresponding to the function of the area is breifly shown, but once I stop moving, the cursor set in SetCursorProperties is shown again.

What is the correct way to use `IDirect3DDevice9::SetCursorProperties` so that I get the default OS cursors on my window non-client area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with various things, a following change in the application has solved the issue for me:

- In a window procedure, when a `WM_SETCURSOR` is received, remember a result of a condition  `(lParam&0xffff)==HTCLIENT` in a global variable `CursorInClient`
- When the global variable `CursorInClient` is false, avoid calling `IDirect3DDevice9::ShowCursor`

Comment: You'd do better listening for the nc hit test messages if your gonna call showcursor